# Function doesnt work

Tags: function, lua

I have this function:

```
wins = {}
players={}
function Wins(name)
        for i,wins in ipairs(wins) do
                if name==wins then
                        return true
                end
        end
        return false
end

function eventNewGame()
for name in pairs(tfm.get.room.playerList) do 
counter[name] = 0
counterTotal[name] = counterTotal[name]
table.insert(wins, name)
end
    if Wins(name) then
            players[name]={wins=0}
print('okay')
    end
```

However, it doesn't work. (It doesn't print 'okay' and does not set players[name]={wins=0}) What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Clarify "it doesn't work". What doesn't work? What is it supposed to do? What does it do instead? Error messages? Unicorns appear? Wrong result?

Comment: It doesn't print 'okay' and does not set players[name]={wins=0}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is nil in the line below, unless there is a *global* variable `name`:

```
if Wins(name) then
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be you're not ending or calling your function in the code you're shown.
You don't end your for loop in the function eventNewGame() and you never declared name, causing it to be nil. Another thing may be in

```
if name==wins then
```

you're comparing to a table value and not a value from the table. So first you need to declare name then you need to explicitly state what it's comparing to such as

```
if name == wins.var then
```

or

```
if name == wins[1] then
```

or

```
if name == wins[var] then
```

Hopefully this makes sense and helps.